# Solving differential equation $x y^2 y' = x+1$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am asked to solve the following differential equation:

$$
x y^2 y' = x+1
$$

My process was

$$
\begin{align*}
x y^2 y' &= x+1\\
xy^2 \frac{dy}{dx} &= x+1\\
y^2 dy &= \frac{x+1}{x} dx\\
\int y^2 dy &= \int \frac{x+1}{x} dx\\
\int y^2 dy &= \int dx + \int \frac{1}{x} dx\\
\frac{y^3}{3} &= x + \ln |x| + C\\
y &= \sqrt[3]{3 \left( x + \ln |x| + C \right)}
\end{align*}
$$

but when I was checking my result on [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=xy%5E2y%27%20%3D%20x%2B1) I noticed that it was given in a different way.

[image]

Is my result incorrect? What caused the results to be different? Is it the absolute value sign of the $\ln$?

Thank you.

Comment: Looks the same to me.

Comment: Well, that is simply because there are three cubic roots of most numbers.  If $y=y_1$ is a solution, then $y=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi\text{i}}{3}\right)y_1$ and $y=\exp\left(-\frac{2\pi\text{i}}{3}\right)y_1$ are also solutions.  Only when you put a restriction that the solution be real-valued, then you will get only one of them.  For Wolfram Alpha, $(-1)^{1/3}=\exp\left(\frac{\pi\text{i}}{3}\right)$.

Comment: Your answer is correct. Wolfram Alpha just simplified it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, every real number has three cube roots: a real one, and two complex ones. The cube roots of 1, for instance, are $1, -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$, and $-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$. When you took the cube root in solving for $y$, you only considered the real cube root (which is totally fine if you're only interested in real-values functions); WolframAlpha was more general, and gave solutions for all three cube roots. Sort of like how when you have $y^2 = x$, this gives two solutions for $y$: $y = \sqrt{x}$ and $y = -\sqrt{x}$.

Also, with regards to the absolute value, both $\ln(x)$ and $\ln(|x|)$ are valid antiderivatives of $\frac{1}{x}$, so you're correct there.

Comment: Thank you @florence, best regards!